# Why does R.color.myColor return wrong color and getColor() return correct?

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

I have noticed that when I use `R.color.myColor`, I get a wrong color. But, at the same time, using `getColor(R.color.myColor)` gives the correct color. For example, I have a `#3971e3` color in my app, it gives a purple color when using `R.color.myColor` but perfectly fine when using `getColor(R.color.myColor)` or `Color.parseColor("#3971e3");`.

Why is this so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.color.myColor` isn't the actual color code.  It's a resource id that can be used to look up the color code via `getColor`.  The reason for this is that the actual color of the resource can change based on theme, locale, or a dozen other options if you want it to.  So if you need the actual color code, call `getColor`.